# End of 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be an irreducible, orientable, open 3-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group, this gives us a Scott's Core $C\hookrightarrow M$ so that the inclusion is an homotopy equivalence and such that the ends of $M$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the components of $M\setminus int(C)$.

Let $\mathcal E$ be an end and $\partial_{\mathcal E} C$ be the boundary component facing it. I want to show that the inclusion $\partial_{\mathcal E} C\hookrightarrow Z$, for $Z$ the component of $M\setminus int(C)$ containing $\mathcal E$, is an isomorphism on $H_1$.

I can get surjectivity but I fail to get injectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H_i(M,C)=0$ by assumption that the inclusion of $C$ is a homotopy equivalence. Now use excision on the interior of $C$ to see that $H_i(M \ \text{int }C,\partial C)=0$. But $(M \setminus \text{int } C,C)$ is the disjoint union of the spaces you're interested, and (relative) homology is additive under disjoint union, hence all of your groups are zero.

(If one is pedantic they say "You need the set you're excising to have closure contained in $C$! But just take a tubular neighborhood of the boundary etc.)

Comment: Why does Whitehead's theorem imply the deformation retraction? And if there's one, why would the end deformation retract onto $\partial _{\mathcal E} C$? I guess I'm just missing some nice properties that you used.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela: Whitehead's theorem for inclusions of subcomplexes says that there exist a deformation retraction; see eg Hatcher. But I'm now worried about your second question.

Comment: @DanielV I have completely changed the answer. I do not believe my first answer was correct.

Comment: okay thanks, that sounds better. But concerning the original answer: what are your thoughts on the homotopy type at the ends? Probably we might know the core's complement components at the tame ends?

Comment: @DanielV I'm unsure. So the only thing left is to figure out that the relative $\pi_1$ is zero, but I don't really know how to do this... I would be interested if you had any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the follow-up question you asked in the comments to Mike's answer.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $C\subset M$ is a Scott compact core of an open irreducible 3-manifold $M$. Then for each component $E\subset M- int(C)$ (informally known as an "end" of $M$), for the (necessarily connected) boundary surface  $S=\partial E$, the inclusion $i: S\to E$ induces an isomorphism $i_*$ of fundamental groups.

**Proof.**

1. First, let us check the harder part, the injectivity of $i_*$. (It is harder since it uses some nontrivial results of 3-dimensional topology.)  I will work in the PL category. Suppose that $i_*$ is not injective. Then, by the Loop Theorem, there exists a simple loop $L\subset S$ bounding a properly embedded disk $D_1\subset E$ such that $L$ does not bound a disk in $S$. However, the inclusion $C\to M$ is $\pi_1$-injective. Therefore,  the loop $L$ as above, is null-homotopic in $C$. By the Dehn Lemma, since $L$ is simple, it bounds a properly embedded disk $D_2\subset C$. (This is a historic accident that one of the results I use is called a *theorem* and the other is called a *lemma*, both are hard, with the first correct proof due to Papakyriakopoulos.) Since $M$ is irreducible, the 2-sphere $D_1\cup D_2$ bounds a 3-ball $B\subset M$.  Let $S':= S\cap B$. This subsurface of $S$ has exactly one boundary component, namely, $L$.  I claim that $S'$ is is the 2-disk, which will contradict the fact that $L$ does not bound a disk in $S$. Suppose not. Then the interior of $S'$ contains two simple loops $a, b$ which intersect transversally in exactly one point. Therefore, one of these loops, say, $a$, is homologically nontrivial in $C$. But $a$ is contained in the 3-ball $B\subset M$ and, hence, is homologically trivial in $M$.  (Let me know if you want to see a proof.) Therefore, the inclusion map $C\to M$ is not a homotopy-equivalence. A contradiction. Thus, $i_*$ is injective.
2. I will now prove the surjectivity of $i_*$. Let $C'$ denote $(M - E) \cup S$. Since the inclusion $C\to M$ is $\pi_1$-surjective, so is the inclusion $C'\to M$. By  the Seifert - van Kampen theorem, the fundamental group of $M$ is the pushout of the diagram 
   $$
   \pi_1(C')\leftarrow \pi_1(S)\rightarrow \pi_1(E). 
   $$ 
   If $i_*$ is not surjective, the homomorphism $\pi_1(C')\to \pi_1(M)$ cannot be surjective either: This is a consequence of the group-theoretic fact that if you have a group amalgam 
   $$G=G_1 \star_{G_3} G_2$$ 
   and $G_3\ne G_2$ then $G_1\ne G$. A contradiction.  **qed**

Comment: Very clear, thank you. Note that the OP is not @DanielValenzuela.

Comment: Just came across this searching for something. Fyi, the argument above isn’t quite right. You need to assume S is incompressible to get the surjectivity part. It’s not true otherwise, e.g. you can have a knotted core for an open solid torus, and the boundary won’t pi1 surject onto the corresponding end. The problem is the group theory at the end. That only works for amalgams where the subgroup injects.

Comment: @biringer: 6 years later I do not remember what was I thinking. You are right, for the group-theory argument to go through one needs incompressibility. However, surjectivity of the induced map $\pi_1(S)\to \pi_1(E)$ (in the context of the Scott compact core) holds regardless of incompressibility of $S$. I will add a proof later on (I do not think OP cares at all about this).

Comment: No worries! You don’t get surjectivity, though. A thickened knot in a solid torus that goes once around the core is a compact core. The complement can have very complicated pi1, and usually won’t be surjected by Z^2. (Replace solid torus by handlebody and you get hyperbolic examples too.)